# How to calculate the confidence level?

Tags: statistics

So I need to get the value from the Z table in order to compare it using the Kolmogorov method and evaluate whether my hypothesis is correct. In order to do that as far as I'm aware I need to calculate the confidence level. I have a 100 numbers. The solution that I found is to divide the standard deviation by 10 (the square root of 100). I seem to get 0.092 which is a bit too low I believe. What else do I need to do?

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier the context is that I have a 100 random numbers from -2 to 1 and I drew a histogram of 10 intervals for them. I created a hypothesis that they are in a uniform distribution and now I need to prove it using Kolmagorov's method. I need to find out how to calculate the confidence level in order to do that.

Comment: From what I understand, the confidence level isn't something you *calculate* here, it's something you *choose*, and then depending on your data you can reject the hypothesis or you can't.